# Show $\int_{s}^{\infty} f(x)dx = \mathcal{L} \{\frac{F(t)}{t}\}$ given $f(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-xt}F(t)dt$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, laplace-transform

I'm trying to derive this to show that

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{F(t)}{t} dt$$

and use that to prove

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin t}{t} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

How do I go about proving that $$\int_{s}^{\infty} f(x)dx = \mathcal{L} \{\frac{F(t)}{t}\}$$ given $$f(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-xt}F(t)dt$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that $$\frac{e^{-st}}{t} = \int_s^{\infty} e^{-xt} dx.$$ Then

$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-st} \frac{F(t)}{t} dt = \int_0^{\infty} \int_s^{\infty} e^{-xt} dx F(t) dt = \int_s^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-xt} F(t) dt dx = \int_s^{\infty}f(x)dx, $$ where in the second equality I have assumed that $F$ is nice enough so that you can exchange the order of integration.

Comment: Thanks so much! Since $F(t)$ is a function of $t$, it should allow the exchange in order of integration!

Comment: In general that would not be enough, but for $F(t) = \sin t$ it works by virtue of the fact that you have $e^{-xt}$ and one of your lower limits is greater than zero. From the way you asked your question I didn't think this was a particularly important sticking point so I glossed over it, but if you're interested look up Fubini's theorem and Tonelli's theorem.